# Slow loop aggregating rows and columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column named 'UserNbr' and a column named 'Spclty', which is composed of elements like this:

```
[['104', '2010-01-31'], ['215', '2014-11-21'], ['352', '2016-07-13']]
```

where there can be 0 or more elements in the list.

Some UserNbr keys appear in multiple rows, and I wish to collapse each such group into a single row such that 'Spclty' contains all the unique dicts like those in the list shown above.

To save overhead on appending to a DataFrame, I'm appending each output row to a list, instead to the DataFrame.

My code is working, but it's taking hours to run on 0.7M rows of input. (Actually, I've never been able to keep my laptop open long enough for it to finish executing.)

Is there a better way to aggregate into a structure like this, maybe using a library that provides more data reshaping options instead looping over UserNbr? (In R, I'd use the data.table and dplyr libraries.)

```
# loop over all UserNbr: 
#   consolidate specialty fields into dict-like sets (to remove redundant codes);
#   output one row per user to new data frame
out_rows = list() 
spcltycol = df_tmp.column.get_loc('Spclty')                
all_UserNbr = df_tmp['UserNbr'].unique()
for user in all_UserNbr:
    df_user = df_tmp.loc[df_tmp['UserNbr'] == user]
    if df_user.shape[0] > 0:   
        open_combined = df_user_open.iloc[0, spcltycol]   # capture 1st row
        for row in range(1, df_user.shape[0]):       # union with any subsequent rows
            open_combined = open_combined.union(df_user.iloc[row, spcltycol])
        new_row = df_user.drop(['Spclty', 'StartDt'], axis = 1).iloc[0].tolist()
        new_row.append(open_combined)
        out_rows.append(new_row)

# construct new dataframe with no redundant UserID rows:
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out_rows, 
                      columns = ['UserNbr', 'Spclty'])
# convert Spclty sets to dicts:
df_out['Spclty'] = [dict(df_out['Spclty'][row]) for row in range(df_out.shape[0])]
```

The conversion to dict gets rid of specialties that are repeated between rows, In the output, a Spclty value should look like this:

```
{'104': '2010-01-31', '215': '2014-11-21', '352': '2016-07-13'}
```

except that there may be more key-value pairs than in any corresponding input row (resulting from aggregation over UserNbr).

Comment: Off the topic, but is there anything more useless than down-voting a question without an explanation?

Comment: didn't downvote, yet, but you might look into this before posting a question;     https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. SO is not for codereview or is a code writing service.

Comment: Thanks, Zanshin -- but this is not a problem that easily fits that framework.

Comment: Thanks, Zanshin -- but this is not a problem that easily fits that framework. First, my code works -- it's just too slow. Second, if I create a "minimal" example it won't prove anything because there won't be enough data to test the issue. Third, I addressed "complete" by providing a thorough description of the problem and my approach. Fourth, I don't think we need "verifiable" because, again, my code works, and too much data is required for a proper  test.

Comment: My problem is that I can't see which structure, transformation, or assignment could be generating so much overhead. Plus, people who post without explaining what they are trying achieve usually get asked to do so by the responders. 

As I mentioned, I avoided serially appending to a DataFrame,, thinking it would be fast to do it to a list. My execution time seems to grow exponentially with the number of input rows, but I can't see why.

Comment: If I abstract the code too much I might eliminate the culprit from the posted snippet. If I knew exactly what to ask I would probably then see the answer in front of me, but this issue probably involves specialist knowledge of Pandas engineering.

Comment: If this topic is simply too theoretical for this forum then I'm open to suggestions, please.

Comment: Update: I tried disabling the garbage collector before appending to the big list, but it made no difference. (That bug was reported fixed in a previous Python release, anyway, so it was a desperate act.)

Answer (score 0):

I withdraw this question.

I had hoped there was an efficient way to use groupby with something else, but I haven't found any examples with a complex data structure like this one and have received no guidance.

For anyone who gets similarly stuck with very slow aggregation problems in Python, I suggest stepping up to PySpark. I am now tackling this problem with a Databricks notebook and am making headway with the pyspark.sql.window Window functions. (Now, it only takes minutes to run a test instead of hours!)

A partial solution is in the answer here:

[PySpark list() in withColumn() only works once, then AssertionError: col should be Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588451/pyspark-list-in-withcolumn-only-works-once-then-assertionerror-col-should)