# PySpark list() in withColumn() only works once, then AssertionError: col should be Column

Tags: pyspark

I have a DataFrame with 6 string columns named like 'Spclty1'...'Spclty6' and another 6 named like 'StartDt1'...'StartDt6'. I want to zip them and collapse into a columns that looks like this:
`[[Spclty1, StartDt1]...[Spclty6, StartDt6]]`

I first tried collapsing just the 'Spclty' columns into a list like this:

```
DF = DF.withColumn('Spclty', list(DF.select('Spclty1', 'Spclty2', 'Spclty3', 'Spclty4', 'Spclty5', 'Spclty6')))
```

This worked the first time I executed it, giving me a new column called 'Spclty' containing rows such as `['014', '124', '547', '000', '000', '000']`, as expected.

Then, I added a line to my script to do the same thing on a different set of 6 string columns, named 'StartDt1'...'StartDt6':

```
DF = DF.withColumn('StartDt', list(DF.select('StartDt1', 'StartDt2', 'StartDt3', 'StartDt4', 'StartDt5', 'StartDt6'))))
```

This caused `AssertionError: col should be Column`.

After I ran out of things to try, I tried the original operation again (as a sanity check):

```
DF.withColumn('Spclty', list(DF.select('Spclty1', 'Spclty2', 'Spclty3', 'Spclty4', 'Spclty5', 'Spclty6'))).collect()
```

and got the assertion error as above.

So, it would be good to understand why it only worked the first time (only), but the main question is: what is the correct way to zip columns into a collection of dict-like elements in Spark?

Comment: have you tried to save the result dataframe in to two different variable name. like: `DF_Spclty = DF_tmp.withColumn('Spclty', list(DF_tmp.select('Spclty1', 'Spclty2', 'Spclty3', 'Spclty4', 'Spclty5', 'Spclty6')))` and `DF_StartDt = DF_tmp.withColumn('StartDt', list(DF_tmp.select('StartDt1', 'StartDt2', 'StartDt3', 'StartDt4', 'StartDt5', 'StartDt6'))))`

Comment: I think you may have nailed the reason why I got it to work once only -- the 'Spclty' column existed after the first time, and repeated execution was trying to create a duplicate column name? (I thought `withColumn()` would overwrite the old one,)

Answer (score 4):

`.withColumn()` expects a column object as second parameter and you are supplying a list.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. After reading a number of SO posts I figured out the syntax for passing a set of columns to the `col` parameter, using `struct` to create an output column that holds a list of values:

```
DF_tmp = DF_tmp.withColumn('specialties', array([
        struct(
         *(col("Spclty{}".format(i)).alias("spclty_code"),
         col("StartDt{}".format(i)).alias("start_date")) 
        )
        for i in range(1, 7)
      ]
))
```

So, the `col()` and `*col()` constructs are what I was looking for, while the `array([struct(...)])` approach lets me combine the 'Spclty' and 'StartDt' entries into a list of dict-like elements.